# Variadic functions arguments bad order in some cases

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I was trying to reduce my code and I found something weird with variadic functions (it's most certainly due to my lack of knowledge though)

So I have that piece of code that works :

```
void Text::textTypePtr(Root* text, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, text);
  Interact::ModifiedKey modKey = va_arg(args, Interact::ModifiedKey);
  Keyboard::Key key = va_arg(args, Keyboard::Key);  
  static_cast<Text*>(text)->textType(modKey, key);
  va_end(args);
}
```

and then, this piece of code that reverses the args order

```
void Text::textTypePtr(Root* text, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, text);
  static_cast<Text*>(text)->textType(va_arg(args, Interact::ModifiedKey), va_arg(args, Keyboard::Key));
  va_end(args);
}
```

I'm now scared that the first piece of code worked by some miracle, can someone maybe help me to understand what's going on?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also, I'm not sure what the question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first version is correct. Statements are executed in order, so you can be confident the first variadic argument will be assigned to `modKey` and the second will be assigned to `key`.

The second version is depending on unspecified behavior. The relative order of evaluation of arguments to a function is unspecified. So it can evaluate either `va_arg()` expression first, which means that it could assign the wrong variadic argument to each parameter of the `textType()` function.